# Maven AAR transitive dependencies --> Error

Tags: android, maven

I have a problem to retrieve an AAR transitive dependency from a deployed artifactory library.

Here the **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "x.y.z:B:1.0.0"
}
```

In the **POM file** of the `x.y.x:B:1.0.0`, I have this configuration :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
  <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

But I have an error with Gradle because it search a .jar file instead of .aar file. Do I miss a step?

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sample:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find A.jar (x.y.z:A:1.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://.../x/y/z/A/1.2.5/A-1.0.0.jar
```

Also, the library A contains only a .aar & .pom file on Maven.

> **Information:** All of this libraries are in a same private maven artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. The solution is below if you have the same problem.

I miss to add this line on a library in the pom file.

```
<packaging>aar</packaging>
```